# TransientObjectException when calling findBy... on result from Elastic Search in Grails

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-orm, elasticsearch-plugin

I've successfully set up the elastic search plugin with my grails project running grails 2.5.0. I can search and get results. But certain operations are not possible on the results like calling a method on one domain that interacts with another via GORM's findBy...

Given the Foo class

```
class Foo {
   static searchable = true

   def getBars() {
      return Bar.findAllByFoo(this)
   }
}
```

The Bar class

```
class Bar {
   Foo foo
   static searchable = true
}
```

The third line below will result in a TransientObjectException

```
def result = Foo.search("Some parameter")
def foo = result.searchResults.first()
def bars = foo.bars //Fails
```

The exception

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.example.Foo. Stacktrace follows:
Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: org.example.Foo
Line | Method
->>  105 | methodMissing    in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
```

Searching the web for this issue gives a lot of hits relating with GORM save operations which is not the issue here I guess. This goes perfectly fine if the object is not fetch from an elastic search result, why I think this issue is related to the plugin.

```
def foo = Foo.get(1)
def bars = foo.bars //Works
```

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using? Are you using https://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that plugin ':elasticsearch:0.0.4.6'

Answer (score 0):

Check [official documentation](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/mapping.html#parentChild):

> To map a parent/child relationship, the child element must either
>   contain the parent element as a component or reference it as a
>   referenced document. This component must be mapped as a parent in the
>   child element.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> class ParentElement {
> …
> }
>
> class EmbeddingChild {
>     ParentElement parentElement
>
>     static searchable = {
>         parentElement parent: true, component: true
>     }
> }
>
> class ReferencingChild {
>     ParentElement parentElement
>
>     static searchable = {
>         parentElement parent: true, reference: true
>     }
> }
> ```

There is also [good example at the end](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/example.html#parentChildExample).

Comment: Thanks, but I've read the documentation and I couldn't find  anything that applies to my situation. I've tried adding `static searchable = {
        foo component: true
    }` to the Bar class without any luck. I don't think I can add anything more to the Foo class because it doesn't include any referencing property to Bar.